# Expo SecureStore Limitations

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I will build an app that will have 2 Features

- Store a unique secret that will never leave the Device
- Store a secret that has to be backed up

For the first Feature, I would choose the following native API's

- Android: [Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)
- iOs: [Secure Enclave](https://support.apple.com/de-at/guide/security/sec59b0b31ff/web)

For the second Feature, I would choose the following

- Android: [KeyValue Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup)
- iOs: [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services)

Now when I look at the Documentation of Expo's [SecureStore](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) I can see, that they use Keychain Services for iOs and the Keystore for Android. This is a Problem for me, because for my features I need to differentiate between a store that is backed up and a store that will never leave the device.

So my questions are:

Did I pick my native API's wrong, or missunderstood something?

Is there another Expo API I can use or does Expo simply not support what I need?

(I have also posted this in [Expo's Dev Forum](https://forums.expo.dev/t/securestore-limitations/63492))

Comment: In case Expo doesnt support what I need, i would still use it and go for [Adding Custom Native Code](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall expo supporting that. You need to try searching for another react native module outside of expo or writing your own. Not sure if expo already changed it, but if you want to write a custom native module with expo you will have to use something called "Bare Workflow". That means you need to make your app a normal React Native app with Expo's Unimodules.